# Deployment to the application failed in build_and_push_image-2 circleci

Tags: node.js, linux, docker, amazon-eks, circleci

```
Issue : Deployment to the application failed in build_and_push_image-2
Pipeline : Circle-CI
Hosted Environment : EKS
Docker Image : node: 12.22.10-stretch-slim

Error : Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-ox5ofr/PyYAML/

Script to Install Dependencies : 
name: Install dependencies
          command: |
            apk add py-pip
           apk add bash && apk add rsync
           pip install awscli
           apk add --update nodejs npm





To overcome the issue reported above , script to Install Dependencies is updated as below.

name: Install dependencies
          command: |
            apk add --update --no-cache python3 py3-pip
            apk add --update python3-dev
            apk add bash && apk add rsync
            pip3 install --no-cache --upgrade pip setuptools
            pip3 install awscli
            apk add --update nodejs npm
```

After above update to circle-CI pipeline, deployment is successful, but the application is down, as the Pod is failing with CrashLoopBackOff error:

On investigating the Pod logs, Pod is restarting with below error,

```
Error [ERR_IPC_DISCONNECTED]: IPC channel is already disconnected
    at ChildProcess.target.disconnect (internal/child_process.js:833:26)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/@pm2/agent/src/InteractorClient.js:238:13)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at ChildProcess.target.disconnect (internal/child_process.js:833:12)
   at Timeout._onTimeout (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/@pm2/agent/src/InteractorClient.js:238:13)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7) {
  code: 'ERR_IPC_DISCONNECTED'
```